# Unable to add record. Joinkey of table not in recordset?MS Acess 2007

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have been trying to have a form where I can enter all my patient details along with the medicines prescribed. I have created 5 tables for this.

- **tblpatients** for patient details with Patient ID as primary.
- **tblvisit** for visit details like visitdt,tests,etc, with Visit_ID as primary.
- **tblmedicines** for list of medicines(which I can add dynamically).
- **tblqnty** for specific doses and qnty mentioned during a specific visit.

I have created a form with all patient and visit info and a subform inside the form with medicines and qnty(in tabular form).

Now I am facing 2 issues:

1. I am unable to set the subform to blank by default on load the mainform as new record. I have tried that even on subform but not working.
2. While trying to add a record in the subform I receive the error message 
   "Unable to add record. Joinkey of table tbkqnty not in recordset?"

[image: Database relationship]
[image: Data entry Form and subform]

Answer (score 0):

1) If with 'blank' you mean 'empty': look at point 2)

2) In the recordset of your subform you MUST have the field Visit_ID.
   If you don't want to show it in the subform set it to `Visible: No`

3) Link the two forms (main- and sub-) with `Visit_ID` (Table `tblVisit`) as
   `Link Master Field` and `Visit_ID` (Table `tblmedicines`) as 
   `Link Child Field` in the Main form 'Data' Property Sheet TAB.

4) In the subform, in the `before_Update event` set

```
Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

   Visit_ID = Me.Parent!Visit_ID

End Sub
```

(supposed that Control Names are equal to the Field Names).

This will ensure that all records in the child table `tblMedicines` are
   related to one record in the table `tblVisit`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Appreciate your help! But need more clarity as I am a novice in relationship and access.   1. In Point 2, when you say Visit_ID does it refer to Visit_ID in table tblvisit. 2. How to link the Master and Child field from Data Property sheet. These form and sbform were created based on queries. SOrry if that sounds silly.

Comment: Please visit the Microsoft Site where you can find good tutorials.
"Database design basics - Access" on support.office.com